# Why does Go compiler not find a library I use?

Tags: go

I have a simple Go program in directory `x`:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "os"

        "github.com/yanzay/tbot"
)

func main() {
        bot, err := tbot.NewServer(os.Getenv("TELEGRAM_TOKEN"))
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        bot.Handle("/answer", "42")
        bot.ListenAndServe()
}
```

`x/pkg/windows_386/github.com/yanzay` contains the file `tbot.a` with the `tbot` library used in my program. `x/src/github.com/yanzay/tbot` contains the source code of that library.

When I run `go build main.go`, I get this output:

```
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:12:21: undefined: tbot.NewServer
```

How can I make sure that Go compiler finds the `tbot` package in the `x/pkg` or `x/src`?

Comment: Go finds the library. It doesn't find the NewServer function. Are you sure there's such a function ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret You were right. Submit your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undefined: tbot.NewServer` means Go finds the tbot library but doesn't find the `NewServer` function.

There's no such function in [this library](https://godoc.org/github.com/yanzay/tbot).

---